# How to create an extern alias for System.Core?

Tags: c#, linq, alias, extern

I absolutely need an extern alias for `System.Core` in my project. Unfortunately, in a .Net 4.0 project, you cannot even add a reference to `System.Core` because, apparently, the build system includes it by default. Does anyone have any idea on how I can coerce the system to let me specify an extern alias for this lib? Thanks!

Comment: Does it also include it when targeting an older framework version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is old but I ran into the same problem. As far as I understood, this is due to Visual Studio implicitly adding a reference to System.Core.

You can override this by editing your csproj msbuild file and adding:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <AdditionalExplicitAssemblyReferences/>
</PropertyGroup>
```

at the end.

This disables any `AdditionalExplicitAssemblyReferences` that I assume Visual Studio has passed to MSBuild using the /p[roperty] switch.
Of course, we now still have to add the System.Core reference as it is no longer referenced. Do so by adding

```
<Reference Include="System.Core">
   <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
   <Aliases>global,ActualSystemCore</Aliases>
</Reference>
```

to the `ItemGroup` that contains references (or a new one).

You can now refer to a `System.Core` type using

```
ActualSystemCore::System....
```

Comment: If there is no conflict with other identifiers, it is _also_ legal to use an ordinary period, as in `ActualSystemCore.System. ...`.